# Wordpress plugin não funciona chamada de FORM externo

Tags: php, wordpress, plugin-wordpress

Estou tentando responder ao um form enviado por um terceiro para o meu Wordpress. 
Criei então um plugin para receber esse form e coloquei dentro da pasta do plugin o arquivo do form:

```html
<form action="http://www.meusite.com/staging/wp-content/plugins/Integrador/integrador.php" >
  <input name="codigo_cliente" value="0" />
  <input name="nome" value="XY" />
  <input name="fone" value="99 9999.9999" />
  <input name="url_xml" value="http://www.site.com/arquivo.xml" />
  <input type="submit" name="registernow" value="Inscreva-se"/>
</form>
```

O caminho do arquivo está OK, o form chega até o endereço, porém ao chegar o resultado é:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function plugin_dir_url()

Não consigo nem definir o caminho do plugin.
Segue o codigo:

```
<?php
define('INTEGRADOR_FOLDER_NAME','Integrador');
define('INTEGRADOR_VERSION','0.0.1');
define('INTEGRADOR_PLUGIN_NAME','Integrador Plugin');
define('INTEGRADOR_SLUG','Integrador/integrador.php');

// Plugin Folder URL
define( 'INTEGRADOR_URL', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) );
// Plugin Folder Path
define( 'INTEGRADOR_DIR', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );

$locale = get_locale();
load_textdomain( 'templatic', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'languages/'.$locale.'.mo' );



/*if(isset($_POST['notificationType']) && $_POST['notificationType'] == 'transaction'){*/
    //Todo resto do código iremos inserir aqui.     

include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' 
if ($_REQUEST['codigo_cliente'] != ''){

    echo '<h1>VOU REGISTRAR ESSE USUÁRIO... AGUARDE....</h1>';
    if(file_exists(INTEGRADOR_DIR.'vista/vista_registro.php')){
            include_once(INTEGRADOR_DIR.'vista/vista_registro.php');

            exit;
        }
}
```

Tem mais um monte de códigos depois deste início.

Se eu acessar o site primeiro no navegador e enviar o form tudo funciona(sessão ATIVA). Mas se eu mandar sem entrar no site: **Erro nas funções básicas do wordpress.**

É como se o wordpress não tivesse carregado.

Podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Seu erro está na action do form:

```
<form action="http://www.meusite.com/staging/wp-content/plugins/Integrador/integrador.php" >
```

Esse caminho é reconhecido pelo servidor do WordPress como um acesso direito ao arquivo, portanto somente esse arquivo é carregado, nada mais.

O formulário precisa enviar o `POST` ou `GET` para uma URL reconhecida no nas regras de reescrita do WordPress, pra que a aplicação seja carregada antes. Se o seu plugin está ativo, pode ate mesmo mandar para a home, apesar das boas praticas sugerirem criar endpoints só pra isso:

```
<form action="http://www.meusite.com/" >
```

-

```
// 'plugins_loaded' é a primeira action disponível para plugins ativos
//  mas pode ser cedo demais, dependendo das outras informações do site que você precisar. 
//  Se não funcionar, tente 'init' ou 'wp'
//  https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'responde_form' );
function responde_form() {
    $request = wp_unslash( $_REQUEST );

    if ( ! isset( $request['codigo_cliente'] ) {
        return;
    }  

    // aqui começa a processar os dados
}
```